# How to exclude Maven modules on command line

Tags: maven

Purportedly you can exclude modules on the command line for example by running command like

```
mvn clean install -pl \!modulename
```

This does not seem to work (anymore).

Btw, include the module also doesn't work

```
mvn clean install -pl modulename
```

Maven reactor will not find the module and fail.

```
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: modulename -> [Help 1]
```

The module `modulename` does exist however. Reactor will produce its name in the list of build modules when doing an ordinary build.

```
[INFO] modulename
```

Is there a way to exclude modules on the command line? I don't want to change the pom file if it all possible.

Comment: If you want to do this more often I suggest to look into [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Also, usually what is printed is the value from the `<name>` tag, not the value from `<module>modulename</module>` - which should be the subdirectory the module is in, and be the same as the `<artifactId>` of that module.

Comment: What's the maven version? Am guessing 3.x ?

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -pl :modulename` or `-pl '!:modulename'`

Comment: you can also exclude all modules with --non-recursive

Answer (score 25):

Lets say in your parent pom.xml, your module structure is this:

[image]

Then if I want to exclude modules "core" and "app1", the command would be:

```
mvn -pl '!core,!app1' clean install
```

So the end result with the -pl flag is:

[image]

Note:

Put the module names from the parent pom.xml (like above), not the `<name>` in the sub-modules.

Put the -pl flag before "clean install".

Also, there should be no spaces between each of the commas separating the module names.

This is what the build looks like without the -pl flag set:
[image]

Comment: I had to remove quotes from module names to make it work. `mvn -pl !core,!app1 clean install`

Answer (score 1):

if you have a module named: `app-server`, then you can try this:  `clean install -pl !app-server.--`

[For learning more](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230)